# Unknown data type coming from bluetooth module

Tags: ios, objective-c, c

i have the following sample bluetooth module code which im trying to implement in my own app.

```
- (void)receivedData:(unsigned char *)data length:(NSUInteger)len; {
NSLog(@"DATA:  %s", data );}
```

The console is printing out log like this:

```
2013-06-04 17:32:05.408 xyz[155:707] DATA:  0ıÊ
2013-06-04 17:32:05.447 xyz[155:707] DATA:  03803DE

2013-06-04 17:32:05.668 xyz[155:707] DATA:  0ıÊ
2013-06-04 17:32:05.709 xyz[155:707] DATA:  0B403DE
```

I know the bluetooth module is sending a ten byte packet. I want the information from the first two bytes. Are these HEX values? How can I convert them to decimal?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Remove semicolon `;` from method `receivedData` definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using C, just use the print f function:

```
printf("%x", DATA[i]);
```

that will print it as hex.  If you want to print it as a string, just print it like this:

```
printf("%s", DATA);
```

Decimal:

```
printf("%d", DATA[i]);
```

It looks like its printing its ascii values right now.

Comment: Be careful with %s, though; it assumes the data is null-terminated, which is probably not the case here. (Otherwise, why pass a length?)